Two-dimensions array 9x9 of integers without using numpy.array (subclassing MutableSequence)
Few days ago I found the next example of howto implement customs list classes via subclassing the MutableSequence from collections.abc.
class TypedList(MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, oktypes, *args):
        self.oktypes = oktypes
        self.list = list()
        self.extend(list(args))

    def check(self, v):
        if not isinstance(v, self.oktypes):
            raise TypeError(v)

    def __len__(self): return len(self.list)

    def __getitem__(self, i): return self.list[i]

    def __delitem__(self, i): del self.list[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, v):
        self.check(v)
        self.list[i] = v

    def insert(self, i, v):
        self.check(v)
        self.list.insert(i, v)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list)

Example of use of TypedList:
    tl = TypedList(int)
    # ok
    tl.append(1)
    # next TypeError will be raised
    tl.append('1')

My Question:
I was wondering if there is way of implementing an two-dimensions SudokuArray(MutableSequence) class in similar manner for mananing a sudoku array in a game?
For giving you an idea, below you can see a possible implementation (non-operative) of that SudokuArray(MutableSequence):
class SudokuArray(MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, n_rows=9, n_columns=9, init_value=None):
        self.n_rows = n_rows
        self.n_columns = n_columns
        self.array = [[init_value for _ in range(0, self.n_columns, 1)] for _ in range(0, self.n_rows, 1)]

    def check(self, row_number, column_number, number):
        if number in self.get_row_values(row_number) or
                                         number in self.get_column_values(column_number) or
                                         number in self.get_nonet_values(row_number, column_number)):
            raise ExistentNumberError("Existent number in row, column or nonet",
                                      number, row_number, column_number)

    def __len__(self): return self.n_rows, self.n_columns

    def __getitem__(self, row_number, column_number): return self.array[column_number][row_number]

    def __delitem__(self, row_number, column_number): del self.array[column_number][row_number]

    def __setitem__(self, row_number, column_number, number):
        self.check(number, row_number, column_number)
        self.array[column_number][row_number] = number

    def insert(self, row_number, column_number, number):
        self.check(row_number, column_number, number)
        self.array.insert(row_number, column_number, number)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.array)

    def get_row_values(self, row_number):
        # todo implement get_row_values method
        pass

    def get_column_values(self, column_number):
        # todo implement get_column_values method
        pass

    def get_nonet_values(self, row_number, column_number):
        # todo implement get_nonet_values method
        pass

class ExistentNumberError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, number, row_number, column_number):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.number = number
        self.row_number = row_number
        self.column_number = column_number

Example of use of SudokuArray:
    sudoku_array = SudokuArray()
    sudoku_array[0][0] = 1
    # next ExistentNumberError will be raised
    sudoku_array[0][0] = 1

Of course I could use numpy.array but I think our 9x9 array is very simple for using numpy. Also I want to avoid dependencies.
Any idea?

There are these issues in your attempt:

The if statement in check lacks an opening parenthesis.
__len__ should return a number, not a tuple.
__getitem__ and similar methods should not take two index arguments, but one. However, this argument can be a tuple (of 2 coordinates)
In __setitem__ the call to self.check has arguments in the wrong order.
A Sudoku always has the same number of rows and columns, so I would not have separate constructor parameters for the number of rows and the number of columns. Just have one parameter.
The insert and __delitem__ methods should not be used on a Sudoku: you don't want to change the number of entries on any row. In the below correction I will still include them, as maybe you have a good reason for this?
The get_***_values methods were not implemented.

Here is the suggested code:
from collections.abc import MutableSequence
from math import isqrt

class SudokuArray(MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, size=9, init_value=None):
        self.size = size
        self.array = [[init_value for _ in range(self.size)] for _ in range(self.size)]

    def check(self, row_number, column_number, number):
        if (number in self.get_row_values(row_number) or
                  number in self.get_column_values(column_number) or
                  number in self.get_nonet_values(row_number, column_number)):
            raise ExistentNumberError("Existent number in row, column or nonet",
                                      number, row_number, column_number)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size * self.size

    def __getitem__(self, coordinates): 
        return self.array[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]]

    def __delitem__(self, coordinates): 
        del self.array[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]]

    def __setitem__(self, coordinates, number):
        self.check(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], number)
        self.array[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] = number

    def insert(self, coordinates, number):
        self.check(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], number)
        self.array[coordinates[0]].insert(coordinates[1], number)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(" ".join(map(str, row)) for row in self.array).replace("None", ".")
                         
    def get_row_values(self, row_number):
        return self.array[row_number][:]

    def get_column_values(self, column_number):
        return [row[column_number] for row in self.array]

    def get_nonet_values(self, row_number, column_number):
        width = isqrt(self.size)
        row_number -= row_number % width
        column_number -= column_number % width
        return [val for row in self.array[row_number:row_number+width]
                    for val in row[column_number:column_number+width]]

Example use:
sudoku = SudokuArray()
sudoku[1, 2] = 9
sudoku[2, 3] = 8
sudoku[5, 5] = 4
sudoku[4, 4] = 3
sudoku[3, 3] = 6
print(sudoku)

